# Clash of Clans base regeneration

Tags: clash-of-clans

Okay, so I'm a Town hall 8 player, nearly maxed out, and I was unable to get onto my base for a week. Well, I have friends from real life in my clan and, after one night of me being off, they contact me and say that my base was destroyed and then rebuilt itself as if I got onto the game (which I did not). From what I understand, your base is rebuilt only after you get back on.

Was I hacked, or am I wrong on this and your base rebuilds after a certain amount of time?

Answer (score 3):

**After your Guard runs out, your base will regenerate automatically**, *even if you haven't logged in*. This allows players to attack abandoned villages, even if they weren't active for 100 days.
So, don't worry. You weren't hacked.

Answer (score 0):

Your shield was probably over and you got attacked again, and the attacker didn't damage you (probably to lose trophies etc) and caused your town to be regenerated.

Comment: Base destruction goes off of the most recent attack, not all of them together?

Comment: @Quickdan I believe that it is the most recent attack.